# Any 3 party controls or ideas to for UItableview pagination like google search result

Tags: uitableview, pagination

[image]Pagination for next, previous and pagenumber

Answer (score 0):

Here is link:

> https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Pagination for next, previous and pagenumber can be just two buttons and you can trigger nextpage action on it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sypaginator maybe it is what you want. Or I believe it can be easily customized to exact form you want.

Another solution for you can be to show an HTML wrapped content in UIWebView...